react-native-document-picker is not working
I implement file uploads in react native but there is one issue in console:

const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

  const pickDocument = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });
      setFile(res);
    } catch (err) {
      if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log('User cancelled the picker');
      } else {
        console.log('DocumentPicker Error: ', err);
      }
    }
  };

  const uploadFile = async () => {
    if (!file) return;

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', {
      uri: file.uri,
      name: file.name,
      type: file.type,
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:1337/api/upload',
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        },
      );

      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>YOUR DOCS</Text>
      <Button title="Pick a document" onPress={pickDocument} />
      {file && <Text>{file.name}</Text>}
      <Button title="Upload Document" onPress={uploadFile} />
    </View>
  );
};

the code seems to be right, imports as well. I restarted an app. It did not help.
Also I linked the dependency, after installed. I will be glad if you can help me !

try installing pods.
run below command in console
cd ios && pod install && cd ..


It seem that your package is not installed properly did you try this install agin
yarn add react-native-document-picker

and also follow to documentation of React Native document picker
for public package
React Native document picker
